# Angular filter by IDs

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I'm wondering how to build a custom filter in AngularJS that filters by ID.

Lets say you have comments, and every comment got a property.

```
A. 1
B. 2
C. 1-1
D. 3
E. 1-2
F. 1-1-1
```

I would like to have it filtered to

```
A. 1
B. 1-1
C. 1-1-1
D. 1-2
E. 2
F. 3
```

Created a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/JdqFD3sQuxSkipZoIWX4?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean *sorted* via the filter. You can use the `orderBy` filter with a custom expression

```
    <li ng-repeat="x in comments | orderBy:'ID'">...</li>
```

Here is the updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Jf3I5ykHBqN6hl4kc5Q4?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for this. I was overthinking it, answer was way to close.